# T-SQL: SELECT related column data for the max two other columns

Tags: t-sql, max

I have table data like the following, where order type is 1 for a quote, and 2 for an order.  Any given po_num can have 0 to many of order_type 1, but should only have only 0 or 1 of order_type 2, or all of the above.

I need to return the max order_num of the max order_type of a given po_num, where the order_num is just an additional (but important) column in my result.

Table data:

```
order_type  po_num  order_num
1           E0102   1013200
1           E0102   1013162
1           E0104   1012161 
2           E0104   1012150
1           E0104   1011449
2           E0107   1010034
2           E0108   1011994
```

Desired result:

```
order_type  po_num  order_num
1           E0102   1013200
2           E0104   1012950
2           E0107   1010034
2           E0108   1011994
```

The closest I can get is this, which still includes the max(order_no) for both order_type of 1, and order_no of order type 2:

```
order_type  po_num  order_num
1           E0102   1013162
1           E0104   1012161
2           E0104   1012150
2           E0107   1010034
2           E0108   1011994
```

Comment: If I understand, you want the max value for a given PO_num, ordertype combo? That is, any order_num having order_type 2 is "greater" than any order_num having order_type 1 for the same po_num?

Comment: Sybase or SQL Server?  If SQL Server, which version?

Comment: Yes, this exact combo. And this is SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Is there any constant info about your PO numbers? That is, will they always begin with "10" or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
select order_type
     , po_num
     , max(order_num)
  from orders o1
 where order_type = (
         select max(order_type)
           from orders o2
          WHERE o2.po_num = o1.po_num
      ) 
 group by po_num,order_type
```

The inclusion of order_type in the group by is an *artifact*, it is required because of how the table is designed.

FWIW, the quotes and orders should be split out into two tables.  When you get weird SQL like this an difficult or conditional unique constraints it is a table design issue.

Comment: Ken, that did it, Thank you... and I agree with the FWIW comment.  However, the data isn't actually used by our ERP in the way I presented it. We are actually overloading column usage for a custom application that is allowing us to avoid paying our ERP vendor big bucks for customizations, and this little SELECT will allow me to get just what we need in the custom app without having to do special coding.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked, and I hear you on the "overloading" to avoid dollar payments, did that myself more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a group by clause. Could you add a

```
having order_type = max(order_type)
```

to your sql?

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx for more details on the 'having' statement.

Comment: I tried that, but I still get the results shown above where I get two rows for E0104, the order_type 1, and order_type 2.  It would seem like this should have worked.

Comment: You can't mix an aggregrated with a non-aggregated value in a having clause.