# SQL One-To-Many join issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, max

Let's say I have two tables in Access. TableLetters and TableNumbers. TableLetters has one column TheLetter and 4 records, A, B, C, & D. TheNumbers is many for one TableLetters record. Say we have two columns in TheNumbersTable [TheLetter][TheNumber]. See below:

```
TheLetters
[TheLetter]
A
B
C
D

TheNumbers
[TheLetter][TheNumber]
A          1
A          2
A          3
B          1
B          2
```

How do I write a query that returns one record for each "TheLetters" record and the MAX "TheNumber" from TheNumbers table or blank if there's no match for TheLetter in TheNumbers table? So I want my result set to be:

```
[TheLetters.TheLetter][TheNumbers.TheNumber]
A                     3  
B                     2  
C                     <NULL>
D                     <NULL>
```

I can get A,3 - B,2 but it cuts out C & D because there's not a match in TheNumbers. I've tried switching my joins all around. I've tried putting an IF in the WHERE clause that says if we have a match return the record from TheNumbers or else give me blank. I can't seem to get the syntax right. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/left-join-right-join-operations-HP001032251.aspx):

```
SELECT l.TheLetter, MAX(n.TheNumber)
FROM TheLetters l
LEFT JOIN TheNumbers n ON l.TheLetter = n.TheLetter
GROUP BY l.TheLetter
```

A left outer join returns *all* rows in the left table, returning data for any correlated rows in the right table, or a single row with the right table's columns set to NULL if there are no correlated rows.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it, should that be "ON l.TheLetter = n.TheLetter"?

Comment: @DontFretBrett Yes it should, sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks! That worked. One thing I forgot to ask -- what if "TheNumbers" had one more column and I wanted to return that column value as well, from the same record that was selected by doing MAX(n.TheNumber). I tried doing MAX(n.TheNumber),(SELECT n.NumberString FROM n WHERE n.TheNumber=MAX(n.TheNumber) and n.TheLetter = l.TheLetter) AS NumberString. It said I cannot have an aggregate function in the WHERE clause. Tks!

Comment: That would be a separate question entirely, but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680254/t-sql-selecting-column-based-on-maxother-column and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761517/t-sql-select-related-column-data-for-the-max-two-other-columns

Answer (score 0):

Left Join should correct as below

SELECT l.TheLetter, MAX(n.TheNumber)
FROM TheLetters l
LEFT JOIN TheNumbers n ON l.TheLetter = n.TheLetter
GROUP BY l.TheLetter